# Socket programming and HTTP requests

Tags: java, sockets, http, serversocket

I have written a server that uses port 8082 to retrieve a webpage which i can then access by entering `localhost:8082` on my browser. The problem i have is that when i click on the other resources on the website, i get the chrome browser `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` message. 
Can someone show me how i can configure my code so that i may access not only the base url but also the other urls referenced on that site?
Here's my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
    String hostUrl = "www.mmix.cs.hm.edu";
    try(ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8082)) {
        System.out.println("Server connected...waiting for client");
        try(Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            InputStream url = new URL("http://"+hostUrl+"/index.html").openStream();
            BufferedReader getUrl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url))){
                for(String line = getUrl.readLine(); line != null; line = getUrl.readLine()){
                    htmlCode = htmlCode.append(line);
                }
                String html = htmlCode.toString();
                toClient.writeBytes(html);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant understand your question, your code should work fine, if you want to download another page just change your hostUrl, cant understand where are you "clicking" resources and what has chrome to do with all this.

Comment: The code works fine for this url `www.mmix.cs.hm.edu`, which is the base url. On that page, i have various other links that i can navigate to, and this is what i'm unable to do.

Comment: You can navigate to with a browser sure, but whats the point of a browser in your question? still cant know whats wrong with your code, just changing the url should download a different page.

Comment: When i enter `localhost:8082`on my browser, i get the webpage `www.mmix.cs.hm.edu`, now once i'm on the page, i would like to navigate to the other links displayed on the page which would then have the format: for example: `www.mmix.cs.hm.edu/gettingstarted.html`. I am unable to do this with my browser. 
My question is how can i change my server-code so that this line:
`InputStream url = new URL("http://"+hostUrl+"/index.html").openStream();` holds not only the base url but also the `/gettingstarted.html`

`

Comment: Shouldn't your code be in a loop handling the requests?  Am I wrong but this code looks like it handles a single request then exits?

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense and i already tried putting everything after the second try in a while loop but it's still not working. 
If i open webpage first, restart the server and click on any of the links on the page, it works.

Comment: I think now i got it. You will need to get the requested URL by the browser (tricky part) then just take the endpoint out from it. Maybe you can start by printing the request, study it, and figure out how to take the endpoint.

Comment: Yes, i thought of the same and i'm working on it right now. I save the GET request header as a string and substring it so that i only have what is left in the middle. 
The problem i'm encountering is appending the substring to `InputStream url = new URL("http://"+hostUrl+"/index.html").openStream();`